# bootstrap dateTime picker plugin on dynamic added element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, element, datetimepicker

I am new to jquery i have added bootstrap datetime plugin on an element after dom load i am adding an element which having same class by which datetime plugin is being called. But unable to call plugin an no console error found.

Comment: You have to recall datepicker after inserting new element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you probably bound datePicker on `ready` event.

The best solution imo would be to bind DatePicker just after you create that element. So:

```
var myDynamicElementCreateFunction = function () {
    // ...
    var $elem = $('<div/>'); // Create your element
    $('#my-elem-container').append($elem);
    $elem.datepicker();
}
```

The second solution would be to use `.on()` event binding.

```
$(function () {
    $('#my-elem-container').on('click', '.my-elem-selector', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.datePicker(); // You should probably check whether datapicker is already attached before binding it. 
    });
});
```

I didn't use datepicker so I don't know if it provides a way to check whether it's already attached to an element. You could try it by checking if `$('#my-element').datePicker` exists.
If that doesn't work you can always make some kind of hash map to track these.

Maybe even datepicker is smart enough to know not to reinitialize twice on same element.

Have in mind that first solution is much better and cleaner imo and you should use it if possible.